# Place a Div(s) with Absolute Position on top of an Image so that it won't move on resize.

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-position, css-animations

Is there a way to force animated elements to stay positioned on top of another image?

**PROBLEM:**
When you resize the browser all of the Animated Elements slide Horizontally and/or Vertically. 
[image: Problem with the elements position on the image on resize]
**Notice** the pink square div [as well as the others] move when I resize the screen, I want it to stay in the same place and **NOT MOVE.**

> I've tried to use absolute position on the div, but that doesn't stop
>   them from moving around on resize. **What can I do to keep the elements in a certain spot on the picture**?

[Please use my fiddle to demonstrate  your solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ra2vdf43/)

**HTML:**

```
<center>
<div id="wrapper">
<img class="buildingtotal img-responsive" src="http://www.penguins-world.com/wp-content/uploads/emperor_penguin.jpg" >

<div id="animation">
<div class="bubble toprow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble toprow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble toprow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble toprow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble bottomrow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble bottomrow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble bottomrow">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="bubble bottomrow">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

        <img class="buildingsolo" src="http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb466/audetwebdesign/jsFiddle%20Demos/Puffins.jpg" >

</div>
</center>
```

**CSS:**

```
.toprow{top:0;}

.bottomrow{top:0; margin-top:15%;}

.bubble {
   height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
}

#animation div:nth-of-type(1) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -8s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -8s infinite alternate;
    animation:fadein 6s ease-in-out -8s infinite alternate;
}
#animation div:nth-of-type(2) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate;

}
#animation div:nth-of-type(3) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 16s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 16s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 16s infinite alternate;

}

#animation div:nth-of-type(4) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 24s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 24s infinite alternate;
    animation:fadein 6s ease-in-out 24s infinite alternate;
}
#animation div:nth-of-type(5) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -16s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -16s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -16s infinite alternate;

}
#animation div:nth-of-type(6) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 40s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 40s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 40s infinite alternate;

}


#animation div:nth-of-type(7) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -24s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -24s infinite alternate;
    animation:fadein 6s ease-in-out -24s infinite alternate;


}
#animation div:nth-of-type(8) { 

    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 32s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 32s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 32s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {           
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {        
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {          
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}

.toprow{top:25%; }
.bottomrow{top:0%; }

.bubble:nth-child(1)
{
    background: #ff0; left:10%;    
}

.bubble:nth-child(2)
{
    background: #333; left:30%;    

}

.bubble:nth-child(3)
{
    background: #f90; left:60%;    

}
.bubble:nth-child(4)
{
    background: #e43; left:80%;    

}
.bubble:nth-child(5)
{
    background: #e38; left:10%;    

}

.bubble:nth-child(6)
{
    background: #338;left:30%;    

}
.bubble:nth-child(7)
{
    background: #fdd; left:60%;    

}
.bubble:nth-child(8)
{
    background: #53d; left:80%;    

}
}

@media(max-width:630px)
{
  #animation {display:none!important;}
  .buildingsolo {display:none !important;}
   .buildingtotal {display:block !important; top:0!important;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each image in a div with `position:relative;`

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;"><!--box goes here--></div>
    <img .../>
</div>
```

You can also try:

```
#wrapper {  position:relative; display:inline-block; margin:0 auto;  }
```

**EDIT**

Make sure the wrapper is the same width as the image, else it will not  work:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display:inline-block;">
```

Comment: The Div boxes with position absolute inside a position relative wrapper doesn't  work https://jsfiddle.net/ra2vdf43/2/  Can you show me how to fix it in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure the `<div>` is the same size as the image. I did this by changing the wrapper to be `display:inline-block;`, but you can do this any way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. Can you explain the logic behind your answer so I can understand it better?

Comment: Yes, what you're doing is this: (1) building a box around the image (`<div>`), and then (2) resizing the box to fit the image exactly (`inline-block`), and then (3) telling the box to be `relative` so that the absolute elements are constrained to be inside the box. Thanks to the constraint, `top:0; left:0` would position it to the top left corner of the box, and not the whole page.

Comment: Thank you very much. The wrapper div like this works for me: position:relative; display:inline-block . Great explanation too!